# Arel: How to cleanly join multiple conditions with OR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

In my Rails app, I loop through an array to create a list of conditions that must be joined by OR. Below is the basic flow of how I currently do so.

```
conditions = nil
set.each do |value|
  condition = value.to_condition
  conditions = conditions ? conditions.or(condition) : condition
end
```

Obviously, it's not beautiful, but I still don't fully know my way around Arel. Does it offer any better way of OR-joining a set of dynamically-generated conditions?

Comment: Incidentally - how do is your `to_condition` method written (in a way that doesn't execute a query right away)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a perfect fit for an `inject` which will give you a one-liner you can use within something else as well:
`conditions = set.inject { |conds, cond| conds.or(cond) }` which can even be written: `set.inject(&:or)` which is very nice.

Comment: Wow — I love `inject`, overuse it, and somehow missed it for this scenario! Thanks! :)

Comment: I believe that it creates a condition which looks like (((c1 or c2) or c3) or c4). Do you know if it's possible to define them as (c1 or c2 or c3 or c4)?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/nodes/or.rb would seem to suggest that Arel's conception of `or` is binary. So, "no" would be the answer to your question.

Comment: what would be the difference? why do you want this, or care?

Comment: @Roman - You can use #expr to remove the unnecessary brackets: `conditions = set.inject { |conds, cond| conds.or(cond).expr }`

@omuriauga - It just looks nicer without the unnecessary brackets.

Comment: to get the (c1 or c2 or c3 or c4) functionality simply do `set.inject { |conds, cond| cond.or(conds) }`

Comment: This is brilliant (and ancient!)  but how can a method like the OP's `to_condition` be written?

Answer (score 1):

There is also a useful plugin for this.

[conditions_helper](https://github.com/electronick/conditions_helper)

It helps to generate complex conditions.

Answer (score -1):

I think that's basically it.  I'd initialize conditions to the base object to avoid the ternary:

```
scope = Article
set.each{|v| scope = scope.or(v.to_condition)}
```

Comment: Using Arel 3.0.3 and activerecord 3.2.16 and Article does not respond to 'or'.