# In Arel, how can I combine a bunch of conditions with OR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I have a setup similar to this:

```
  table = self.arel_table
  nodes = [1,2,3].collect do |c|
    table[:foo].eq(c).and( table[:bar].eq(c) )
  end
```

I then want those condition fragments combined to end up with SQL similar to:

```
WHERE (foo = 1 AND bar = 1) OR (foo = 2 AND bar = 2) OR (foo = 3 AND bar = 3)
```

The closest I have so far is:

```
nodes.inject(nodes.shift) {|memo, node| memo.or( Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(node) ) }
```

I've tried `Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new` in different ways but it never groups how I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arel: How to cleanly join multiple conditions with OR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992393/arel-how-to-cleanly-join-multiple-conditions-with-or)

Answer (score -2):

You might want to use [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel), no need to reinvent the wheel.

With it, your case would look something like: `Model.where {foo.like_any nodes}`

#### Edit:

It will be much easier if you define own sifter, which will look like this (if you enable native extensions):

```
nodes.each do |node|
  where{foo == node & bar == node}
end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
table = self.arel_table
Person.where([1,2,3].collect { |c| table[:foo].eq(c).and(table[:bar].eq(c)) }.map(&:to_sql).join(" OR "))
```

Comment: *to_sql* should not be used down there. See: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/Nodes/Node