# Dynamic query with multiple OR conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

On an `ActiveRecord` model, I'm trying to dynamically create a query that has multiple OR conditions. ie:

```
SELECT * from articles
WHERE (name LIKE '%a%' OR desc LIKE '%a%' OR
       name LIKE '%b%' OR desc LIKE '%b%' OR
       name LIKE '%c%' OR desc LIKE '%c%')
```

I think I'm on the right track using `arel`, but I can't work out how to start off the query.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :title, :text

  def self.search(terms)

    terms = *terms
    t = self.arel_table

    query = terms.reduce(???) do |query, word| 
      search_term = "%#{word}%"
      query.or(t[:title].matches(search_term).or(t[:text].matches(search_term)).expr).expr 
    end

    where(query)
  end

end
```

I originally got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11586487/848668), but the original `query` is a string obviously and not something I can chuck `.or` onto.

What do I need to replace `???` in the `reduce` method to make this work, or do I need to take a completely different path (as I suspect)?

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did to get it working:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :title, :text

  def self.search(terms)
    terms = *terms
    t = self.arel_table

    # generate array of conditions
    query = terms.collect do |word| 
      search_term = "%#{word}%"
      t[:title].matches(search_term).or(t[:text].matches(search_term)).expr 
    end

    # combine conditions
    query = query.reduce {|query, condition| query.or(condition).expr }

    where(query)
  end

end
```