# Arel: Dynamically generate conditions from array of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, arel

I'm looking to generate "or" conditions for a query in a Rails app, from an array of words i want to try to `match` against values in a single column, in Arel. I'm trying to follow advice in a [very similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992393/arel-how-to-cleanly-join-multiple-conditions-with-or) with a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3661605/3357635).

But the OP in that question left out explaining the method `value.to_condition` where he turns his values into conditions. Basically i don't understand how to turn each word string into a chainable Arel condition.

This kind of thing is easy to understand for me when chaining SQL query strings, but in Arel, I don't know how to chain the conditions without executing them — the conditions are straight Ruby.

In the below, `patterns` is my array of words. Each condition should be phrased `Table.arel_table[:text].matches(pattern)` and I'd like each of these conditions joined with an `.or`

```rb
conditions = patterns.inject { |conds, cond| cond.or(conds) }
```

When I try to do this though, I don't understand if or how the chaining is working.

```rb
conditions = patterns.inject do |conds, cond|
  Table.arel_table[:text].matches(pattern).or(conds) 
end
```

Comment: `conditions = patterns.map {|pattern| Table.arel_table[:text].matches(pattern)}.reduce(&:or)` would be my recommendation for this chaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops - it's super easy with Arel.

```rb
Table.where(Table.arel_table[:text].matches_any(patterns))
```

I'd still like to know more about chaining Arel conditions.

Comment: Thank you. Not Arel expert but had a array of word and tried with sending words to match(words) and got inspect (Object doesn't support #inspect). Guess matches_any accepts array and calls match for each element.