# Dynamically Adding OR to Ruby on Rails Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table that is set up like below. Where the boolean values represent if the student is passing a class:

| school_name | student | calculus | chemistry | physics | literature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| central | Sam | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| central | Bill | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| central | Sara | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| central | Harry | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| north | Sam | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| north | Fred | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| west | Jim | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| west | Bill | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

The client side will allow the user to select a student name and then let them select which of multiple subjects to look into. (Little strange of a UI I know) Basically, the user might select something like:

`The Students named Sam across all the Schools that is passing calculus or passing chemistry or passing literature.`

OR the user might select

`The Students named Sam across all the Schools that is passing calculus or passing physics.`

So basically I don't know what combination of OR operators I will need for the resulting query.

I could use the client's request to dynamically write a sql query and execute it, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way with Active Record Queries. I can't think of how dynamically tack on more `.or` to an Active Record Query.

Thanks

Comment: Does this post help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72180226/arel-dynamically-generate-conditions-from-array-of-values

Comment: I think your idea to dynamically write the sql query is the way I would approach the problem